# jupyter notebook wont start on Chrome OS

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have just installed jupyter notebook on my Chromebox (Chrome OS) with pip, and I get the following output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2141, in initialize
    self._init_asyncio_patch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 2117, in _init_asyncio_patch
    nest_asyncio.apply()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 14, in apply
    raise ValueError('Can\'t patch loop of type %s' % type(loop))
ValueError: Can't patch loop of type <class 'NoneType'>
```

This is the output of jupyter --version:

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 7.30.0
ipykernel        : 6.6.0
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.1.0
jupyter_core     : 4.9.1
jupyter_server   : 1.12.1
jupyterlab       : 3.2.4
nbclient         : 0.5.9
nbconvert        : 6.3.0
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.6
qtconsole        : 5.2.1
traitlets        : 5.1.1
```

Any hints what is going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a problem with `nest-asyncio=1.5.2` ([issue](https://github.com/erdewit/nest_asyncio/issues/62)). You can run the following commands to uninstall the existing version of `nest-asyncio=1.5.2` and upgrade to `1.5.3`:

```
pip uninstall nest-asyncio
pip install nest-asyncio==1.5.3
```